# EntityDataSource How do i limit and order by date

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

For the latest news items i have the following code

```
 <asp:EntityDataSource ID="entynews" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="name=CommerceEntities" 
DefaultContainerName="CommerceEntities" EnableFlattening="False" 
EntitySetName="news">
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

How do i limit the records to say five and also order it by a field called startdate to return the most recent news.

Regards
Thanks 
David Buckley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `OrderBy` property e.g.

```
OrderBy="startdate DESC"
```

and the `Select` property e.g.

```
Select="top(5) startdate, Another_Field"
```

to your `EntityDataSource` declaration.